# How to make certain sections of this tree structure collapsed by default?

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, bootstrap

This is my first Salesforce project. I have created all the needed functionality, so now my work is down to styling.  I've implemented a bootstrap tree structure I found online to hold my data. It works fine, but I need help tweaking it.

When a user selects a product, the tree loads the product's stories, issues, and their child tasks. Currently, when this data loads, everything is expanded.
How can I make it so that the child tasks are collapsed by default?

Below is my visualforce code. I don't think info from my controller is required to solve this problem.

Thanks for your time, any input is appreciated!

```
<apex:page controller="SprintPlannerBetaController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardStylesheets="false" readOnly="true">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrapp css & Combined Css -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
function treetoggler() {
$('label.tree-toggler').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(350); 
});    
}   
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        treetoggler();
});
</script>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<apex:outputPanel id="test">
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:form >  
            Products&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedProdId}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ProdSelectList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a,b,test" oncomplete="treetoggler()"></apex:actionSupport>                 
                </apex:selectList>
                <p>
                    Related Sprints&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedSprintId}" size="1" id="a">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SprintSelectList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="b,test" oncomplete="treetoggler()"></apex:actionSupport>
                        </apex:selectList>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Story Status Select&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedStoryStatusId}" size="4" id="storyStatusList" multiselect="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!storyStatusNames}"></apex:selectOptions>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="b,test" oncomplete="treetoggler()"></apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Issue Status Select&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedIssueStatusId}" size="4" id="issueStatusList" multiselect="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!issueStatusNames}"></apex:selectOptions>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="b,test" oncomplete="treetoggler()"></apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedMyStoriesAndIssues}">
                        My Stories And Issues
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="test,b" oncomplete="treetoggler()"></apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:inputCheckbox> 
                </p>


                <p> 
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedMyTasks}">
                        My Tasks
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="test,b" oncomplete="treetoggler()" ></apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:inputCheckbox>
                </p>
        </apex:form>

        <apex:outputPanel id="b" layout="block">
            <div class="well" style="width:1000px; padding: 8px 0;">
                <div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 500px;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">

                        <li>
                            <label class="tree-toggler nav-header">Stories</label>
                            <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                <apex:repeat value="{!StoryWrapperThings}" var="swt">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!swt.theStory}" var="story">
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a href="/{!story.id}" target="_blank">
                                                {!story.Name}</a>&nbsp;{!story.Story_Name__c}&nbsp;|&nbsp;DEV&nbsp;-&nbsp;{!story.Dev_Owner__r.Name}&nbsp;|&nbsp;QA&nbsp;-&nbsp;{!story.QA_Owner__r.Name}&nbsp;|&nbsp;{!story.Status__c}
                                            </label>
                                            <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                                <apex:repeat value="{!swt.theTasks}" var="task">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <li><a href="/{!task.id}" target="_blank">
                                                        {!task.Name}</a>&nbsp;{!task.Task_Name__c}&nbsp;|&nbsp;OWNER&nbsp;-&nbsp;{!task.Task_Owner__r.Name}&nbsp;|&nbsp; {!task.Status__c} </li>
                                                    </label>
                                                </apex:repeat>       
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="tree-toggler nav-header">Issues</label>
                            <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                <apex:repeat value="{!IssueWrapperThings}" var="iwt">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!iwt.theIssue}" var="issue">
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="tree-toggler nav-header"><a href="/{!issue.id}" target="_blank">
                                                {!issue.Name}</a>&nbsp;{!issue.Issue_Name__c}&nbsp;|&nbsp;DEV&nbsp;-&nbsp; {!issue.Dev_Owner__r.Name} &nbsp;|&nbsp;QA&nbsp;-&nbsp; {!issue.QA_Owner__r.Name}&nbsp;|&nbsp; {!issue.Status__c}
                                            </label>
                                            <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                                                <apex:repeat value="{!iwt.theTasks}" var="task">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <li><a href="/{!task.id}" target="_blank">
                                                            {!task.Name}</a>&nbsp;{!task.Task_Name__c}&nbsp;|&nbsp;OWNER&nbsp;-&nbsp;{!task.Task_Owner__r.Name}&nbsp;|&nbsp; {!task.Status__c} </li>
                                                    </label>
                                                </apex:repeat>     
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Here they did what you are asking for with a css rule:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596356/bootstrap-collapsed-on-load

Comment: Ah, thanks for the response, @SteveMunLeeuw! It's on the right track but I still have issues. I've added 
<style type="text/css">
        .tree li ul > li {
        display: none;}
    </style>
to my code. Now when the information loads, the tasks are collapsed, but when I click them they don't expand. Any advice? Sorry, I'm very new to css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle everything to collapse after you call the toggle function in your document ready. Pretty sure this should work.

```
$('label.tree-toggler').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(1000);
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Since I am refreshing output panels, I put this in its own function and called it in my oncompletes. It collapses everything by default, but that definitely put me on the right path.

Comment: There Re a few different ways you an accomplish what you want using jquery. Just depends how you want it to all work. You can also dynamically add/modify CSS classes so you could manipulate all kinds of stuff besides just the toggle

Comment: I got it to work the way I want by messing with the label classes. Thanks!